# CSS image scaling to constrain to window width and not distort

Tags: html, css, background

this is my first question on here so I'm sorry if I don't quite get the terminology.

I have a background image that is serving as a logo divider for the footer information, which I made 2,400px wide so it would display fully across multiple screen sizes. Only problem is that there is a large bottom scroll to the webpage and I would just like it to constrain to the window width, and show more as someone may adjust the webpage width to be larger, or less and it constrains down to be smaller. The closest I got to achieving this was when it was constrained to the width of the window, but it distorted the image.

This is the CSS I'm using currently, it may contain quite a bit of excess elements that are not helping me, I had scoured google for solutions but resorted to coming here.

```
footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png) no-repeat fixed; 
    background-image: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left; 
    background-size: 2400px 68px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
```

}

Comment: My html and css link-
codepen.io/jenngga/pen/RrbQPp 
 I have Commented out quite a few things that weren't working, and sorry its a mess currently, I'm still in the draft/ tweaking stage. Thank you all for being so helpful! 

I do have an update as well, for some reason the image does scale down and up with the window width exactly how i need it on my form page but will not on any other pages...  http://codepen.io/jenngga/pen/ZQzxpO

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  background: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

This way it has the width of the entire screen, and scales when you make the screen smaller.

edit;

HTML:

```
    <footer>

       <div class="footer-test">

          This text will be placed in the footer div. The div class footer-test will have a full-size background image no mather what width it has.

       </div>

    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-test {
  background: url("http://www.cossumswimschools.co.uk/images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100px;
}
```

Let me know!

Comment: hmm, for some reason it still doesn't scale properly. I have tried commenting out some code to see if it is conflicting but still no luck

Comment: Could you post the html/css of the rest of your code? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jenngga/pen/RrbQPp

I uploaded into Codepen, but wasn't sure if I could upload my images into it. I have Commented out quite a few things that weren't working, and sorry its a mess currently, I'm still in the draft/ tweaking stage. Thank you for being so helpful!

Comment: See my edited answer, should work like this if I'm understand your idea correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the **background-size to contain**?

```
footer {
  background: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png) no-repeat fixed; 
  background-image: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

I hope this helps...